# How to add box shadow to kendo mobile drawer?

Tags: ios, css, kendo-mobile, box-shadow

I am using `Kendo angular mobile Drawer`. I want to add the `box shadow` to `drawer`.

How do I add box shadow to drawer?

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. may be helpful for you.

```
 div {
        box-shadow: inset 0 12px  15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), inset 0 -12px  8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 50px;
        background: white;
    }
```